# Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine2, symfony3

```
 protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
 {
    $client = new Client();

    // Go to the booking.com website
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.booking.com/country.en-gb.html');

    $crawler = $crawler->filter('body#b2countryPage > div#bodyconstraint > div#bodyconstraint-inner > div.lp_flexible_layout_content_wrapper > div#countryTmpl > div.block_third > div.block_header');
    $progress = new ProgressBar($output,$crawler->count());
    $progress->start();

    $sumHotels = 0;

    $sumCountries = 0;

    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');

    $em = $doctrine->getManager();

    $em->getConnection()->exec( 'TRUNCATE TABLE countries');

    foreach ($crawler as $domElement) {

        $CountryName = $domElement->getElementsByTagName('h2')->item(0)->textContent;

        $hotels = $domElement->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->textContent;

        $integer = (int)$hotels;

        $sumHotels = $hotels + $sumHotels;

        $sumCountries = $sumCountries + 1;

        $countries = new Countries();
        $countries->setCountry($CountryName);
        $countries->setHotels($integer);

        $em->persist($countries);

        //$em->flush();

        $progress->advance();
    }

    $em->flush();

    $progress->finish();

    $output->writeln('');

    $output->writeln('All is ok. We are saving<info> '.$sumCountries.' </info>countries and<info> '.$sumHotels. ' </info>hotels');
}
```

При выполнении конс.команды : `doctrine:schema:update`, дает ошибку

> An exception occurred while executing 'TRUNCATE TABLE countries':
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot
>   truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint
>   (`symfony`.`destinations`, CONSTRAINT `FK_2D3343C3F92F3E70` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `symfony`.`countries` (`id`))

Вот сущность Destination:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Countries;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="destinations")
*/
class Destination
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Countries", inversedBy="destinations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $country
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;
    }
}
```

Вот сущность Countries:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="countries")
*/
class Countries
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $hotels;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Destination", mappedBy="countries")
     */
    protected $destinations;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDestinations()
    {
        return $this->destinations;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $destinations
     */
    public function setDestinations($destinations)
    {
        $this->destinations = $destinations;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $country
     */
    public function setCountry($country)
    {
        $this->country = $country;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getHotels()
    {
        return $this->hotels;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $hotels
     */
    public function setHotels($hotels)
    {
        $this->hotels = $hotels;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем проблема то? В ошибке явно написанно, что вам не позволяет очистить таблицу ограничения (`CONSTRAINT`).

Ошибка чисто MySql. Вы не можете очистить таблицу, т.к. есть ограничения по связанным сущностям. Если вы уж идете в обход ORM и выполняете запросы напрямую, то и ошибки сами обрабатывайте.

Для начала вам нужно очистить связанную таблицу `destinations`. А уж потом `countries`. И обернуть все это в транзакцию. Но лучше конечно использовать `DELETE`.

А если вам уж так хочешь очищать таблицу, то можно снять ограничения:

```
$cmd = $em->getClassMetadata(Countries::class);
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$connection->beginTransaction();
try {
    $db = $connection->getDatabasePlatform();
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    $sql = $db->getTruncateTableSql($cmd->getTableName());
    $connection->executeUpdate($sql);
    $connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');
}
catch (\Exception $e) {
    $connection->rollback();
}
```

**PS. Будьте осторожны, т.к. после такого все ваши сущности `Destination` будут ссылаться на новые `Countries` и может быть путаница.**

Вам по сути нужно не удалять все страны, а добавлять новые в БД, если такой нет. Так как название страны вряд ли измениться, то проверять старые страны на изменение вам не нужно, а только получать новые. Лучше логику переделайте.

Comment: Та же ошибка. А куда нужно вставлять этот код?

Comment: А можете еще варианты кода написать а то мучаюсь.

Comment: @MaximYakubenko этот код надо вместо вашего `$em->getConnection()->exec( 'TRUNCATE TABLE countries');`